# Android actionBar.setTitle makes getActivity.setTitle() not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I have an Android App which consists of several Fragments.
Each time the fragment is shown I set the ActionBar title to this fragment.

I did this with

```
getActivity().setTitle("abc");
```

Later in the App I needed to work a bit more with the ActionBar of a Fragment. So I had to change the title like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null)
   actionBar.setTitle("xyz");
```

This works perfectly fine and changes the title to "xyz".
Still when changing to another Fragment that uses setTitle("abc") from the Activity itself, the title still stays at "xyz". Once I've done this for the first time, I can only change the title with the getSupportActionBar() object.

My question is: is this normal? Does this call transform / invalidate the normal Activity-Title somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Activity Source Code, setTitle() method sets the text to actionBar itself.

Consider there are two fragments, A and B.

Fragment A will be shown by default in the Activity.

So later when you update the title from fragment B, you use getSupportActionBar() or getActionBar() method and update the title.

Since this is the recent change that is occured, even if you go back to the previous fragment,that is fragment A, the title will be same, as set in the fragment B.

If you want to change the title again, do it in onResume() method of the fragment A.

Comment: I actually do it onResume() and as I said, using the getSupportActionBar() works fine - even with later calls. It just "breaks" the setTitle() for the Activity.